# Strange excess on shape when trimming or diving shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Illustrator 25.2.2 and have stumbled on an odd issue when I either use trim or divide on certain shapes. It adds a kind of stroke at certain nodes, see below screen shot. I'm not sure how or why this is produced, and keen to now if anyone else has had a similar issue. Shape is one the left and zoomed in portion of issue is one the right.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it probably belongs on [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: @yellowskull, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to toggle CPU/GPU preview (Command-E). Sometimes it's just a glitch with GPU preview.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Command-E solved the issue.